# xsl:attribute: Cannot add attributes to an element if children have been already added to the element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xslt

I have this xml:

https://gist.github.com/kev-omniata-com/9062497

That i'm trying to apply this xsl to:

https://gist.github.com/kev-omniata-com/9062508

using this gem:

https://github.com/glejeune/ruby-xslt

I"m getting the following error:

```
runtime error: file style.xsl line 209 element attribute
xsl:attribute: Cannot add attributes to an element 
if children have been already added to the element.
```

I'm not sure what that means. When I view the xml with firefox and link to the xsl sheet it renders correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shot in the dark, but it may be line `197`:

```
196: <xsl:if test="@*">
197:  <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
198:  <xsl:for-each select="@*">
```

You're adding to the text of the element before setting the attributes later on.  Maybe try moving that down to the bottom of the `<xsl:if>` block?